# How to rearrange multiple view programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift3, view, resize, constraints

**Problem : -** 
I am creating collage frame from the "svg" image file, then I put view, scroll view, image and another UI component programmatically. Now I want to give a user to readjust height width of the frame by dragging edges of view. When any view size changes other relative views will also change.

How to achieve this ??

**What I tried?**

1) Add each section in the frame.

```
let object = ST_Collage(frame: frame , superFrame :  viewCollage.frame, tag : tag )
 object.dragGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dragRecognized(_:)))
        self.viewCollage.addSubview(object.mainView)
```

2) Then add constraint to all relative frame.

```
for i in 0..<arrCollage.count {
    var object = arrCollage[i]
    let frame  = object.sectionFrame

    if frame!.minY <= viewCollage.frame.minY {
        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: object.mainView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem:viewCollage, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.viewCollage.addConstraint(topConstraint)
        object.topDrag.isHidden = true
    }

    if frame!.minX <= viewCollage.frame.minX {
        let leadingConstraint =  NSLayoutConstraint(item: object.mainView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewCollage, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.viewCollage.addConstraint(leadingConstraint)
        object.leftDrag.isHidden = true
    }

    if frame!.maxY >= viewCollage.frame.size.height-1 {
        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: object.mainView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewCollage, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.viewCollage.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
        object.bottomDrag.isHidden = true
    }

    if frame!.maxX >= viewCollage.frame.maxX {
        let trailingConstraint =  NSLayoutConstraint(item: object.mainView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: viewCollage, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.viewCollage.addConstraint(trailingConstraint)
        object.rightDrag.isHidden = true
    }

    object.heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: object.mainView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: object.sectionFrame.size.height)
    object.widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: object.mainView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: object.sectionFrame.size.width)

    self.viewCollage.addConstraint(object.heightConstraint)
    self.viewCollage.addConstraint(object.widthConstraint)

    for obj in arrCollage {

        if obj.sectionFrame != object.sectionFrame {

            let xPoint = abs((obj.sectionFrame.size.width + obj.sectionFrame.origin.x) - object.sectionFrame.origin.x)
            let yPoint = abs((obj.sectionFrame.size.height + obj.sectionFrame.origin.y) - object.sectionFrame.origin.y)

            if xPoint <= 5  {
                let leadingConstraint =  NSLayoutConstraint(item: object.mainView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: obj.mainView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                self.viewCollage.addConstraint(leadingConstraint)
                print("Leading")
            }

            if yPoint <= 5  {
                let bottomConstraint =  NSLayoutConstraint(item: object.mainView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: obj.mainView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                self.viewCollage.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
                print("Bottom")
            }
        }
    }
    arrCollage[i] = object
}
```

3) Just to test increase constant I added pan gesture and increase height constant, but nothing happens.

```
func dragRecognized(_ sender : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if let view = sender.view {
            arrCollage[view.tag].widthConstraint.constant =  arrCollage[view.tag].widthConstraint.constant + CGFloat(2.0)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

**Result: -**
Nothing updating in view.

**Is there is any way to achieve this.** This feature is avaliable in many other apps.

**Referance Image**

Square arrows are just for direction indication where it can be dragged. [image]